# Cant hide popover arrow

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap

Im building an Angular component

Im trying to hide the arrow of bootstrap popover whit CSS but is not working.

Html:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link" placement="bottom-right"
      [ngbPopover]="popContent">
      <fa-icon class="text-white" [icon]="['fas', 'user']" size="lg"></fa-icon>
    </button>

     <ng-template #popContent>Hello!</ng-template>
```

CSS:

```
.popover .arrow {
    display: none !important;
}
```

But if I apply the CSS from inspector, it works

Im using: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: try putting css in global `style.css`, and check if it works.

Comment: Yes works, but I need to hide the arrow only in this component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use pseude-css selectors to achieve this,

```css
:host::ng-deep ngb-popover-window::ng-deep .arrow{
   display: none !important;
}
```

Lets break it down,

when you click on `button`, it will generate `ngb-popover-window` component in dom.

So, from `:host` select `ngb-popover-window` and from `ngb-popover-window` select `.arrow` and set styles.

`:host -> ngb-popover-window -> .arrow`,

to select element from component without affecting global styles, you need to use `ng-deep` as css selector.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version, you can use `showArrow` prop of Popover which is by default `true`